# Javascript event scoping issues in firefox?

Tags: javascript, events, firefox

In our application we are trying to catch the e (event) of all of our ajax calls thru variable scoping.  For example:

```
function whatever (e) {
        stuff();
}

function stuff() {
        thingy();
} 

function thingy() {
        // I have access to e
}
```

Without passing e thru as a parameter child functions should have access to their parent's events.  It is working in chrome and IE but not in firefox, e is always undefined in firefox.  We do not want to have to go thru the hundreds of ajax calls in our app and pass e in every where as a parameter for this to work.  Is there any other way?

Comment: There's something wrong with your question because your specific code example doesn't work in any browser: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ReNKU/.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The arugment `e` is only available to the code directly defined inside of `whatever()` or any function you pass a reference to.  It is not available to functions called from within `whatever()` unless you pass it to them.

Here's an exact implementation of the code in your question that fails in all browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ReNKU/

As for solutions, you could have used local functions and then `e` would have been available to your other two functions like this because they are defined within the scope of `whatever()`:

```
function whatever (e) {
    function stuff() {
        // e is available here
        thingy();
    } 

    function thingy() {
        // e is available here
    }

    // e is available here
    stuff();
}
```

or, you could pass it to each of your original functions as an argument:

```
function whatever (e) {
        stuff(e);
}

function stuff(e) {
        thingy(e);
} 

function thingy(e) {
}
```

This question about available of function arguments has nothing to do with Firefox as that is a javascript implementation choice which is the same everywhere.

If your particular code happens to be working in some other browsers, then apparently there is a global variable named `e` or `e` in some other parent context that it is picking up and that just happens to have the right value in it, but it's not the `e` that is coming from your `whatever(e)` delcaration.  In any case, it's bad to rely on such an implicit behavior.

If you want the argument e to be available to those other two functions, then you have two good choices:

1. Pass it as an argument to them.
2. Define those functions inside the scope of `whatever(e)` so they can see the arguments directly.

---

If what you're really trying to do is get access to the event that happened in an event handler, then you really only need to know this:

If you're using `.addEventListener()`, the event data structure is passed to the event handler as the first argument.  This is true in all browsers that support `.addEventListener()` including IE9.  If you're using `.attachEvent()` in older versions of IE, then the event data structure is in the global variable `window.event` and you can access it there.  One your event handler starts, if you want to make this data structure available to other functions that you call, you should pass it as an argument to them.  Then, their behavior will be entirely browser-safe.

Here's a quick cross browser event registration function that also handles the event difference:

```
// add event cross browser
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, function() {
            // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
            // and get the event data structure from the global variable and
            // pass it to the event handler
            return(fn.call(elem, window.event));   
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you can see:

http://jsfiddle.net/LU4yT/2/

In chrome and IE it works but it fails in FireFox (pay attention to the alert messages).  It is because of the way the browsers handle global events (my assumption, I'm not sure).  Any ideas on how to make this work in Firefox?

Comment: `window.event` is a global variable in some browsers which you should not rely on except for IE.  I've told you exactly what your two options are for fixing it.  What about those options are you not understanding or not interested in implementing.

Comment: @Tanya - your jsFiddle checks for the existence of a non-standard global variable named `event` and uses it if it exists.  You should not be surprised that using non-standard behaviors only works in some browsers.

Comment: @Tanya - I've added a bunch more explanation to my answer.

Comment: "What about those options are you not understanding or not interested in implementing."

-We do not want to have to go thru the hundreds of ajax calls in our app and pass e in every where as a parameter for this to work.

Comment: @Tanya, if you want very poorly written code, then make a global variable and put the event data into the global variable and access it from that in all your other functions.  That's the only other option I know of.  I didn't put it in my answer because it's a horrible design and I would severely chastise anyone who worked on my programming team who did that.  Writing good code is work.  My suggestion is to do the work to write good code.

Answer (score 0):

jfriend00 isn't 100% correct about it not being firefox.  It has everything to do with firefox actually.  Events are globally accessible by name (as long as you know the name of the event) in chrome and in IE.  However, firefox handles events differently than ie/chrome.  I don't know that there is a solution other than passing the event through the chain of functions as a parameter.

Comment: It's the WRONG behavior to code this way for any browser except IE (where you have no other choice).  It is completely non-standard.  In all browsers except IE with `.attachEvent()`, the event data structure is passed as an argument to the event handler and that's where it should be used from.

Comment: Also, the specific code example that the OP used in their question does NOT work in any browser.  That's why this is not a Firefox issue.

Comment: regardless of whether it's WRONG and not standard, you said it wasn't a firefox specific issue.  I'm arguing that it is a firefox specific issue (an issue with the way firefox handles global events compared to how chrome/IE handle them). I do however agree that the best and most standard compliant method is to pass the event through as a parameter.  However, since Tanya doesn't want to have to "go thru the hundreds of ajax calls in our app and pass e in every where as a parameter" I'm assuming that it will be pretty memory intensive to pass an event through all over the app.

Comment: I think the way the problem was worded may have caused misunderstanding between what I think and what you think jfriend00.

Comment: I think you've made the OP's question into a generic question about the event structure which is always an argument to the callback given to `.addEventListener()` and sometimes in a global variable named `event`.  While the OP's question mentions the term event, ALL their code uses an argument named `e`.  When answering a question about the specific code they've provided, the question is not browser-specific at all.  Their code fails in ALL browsers as the jsFiddle I've provided illustrates.  It is true, we are answering different questions.

Comment: If the OP wants to ask a question purely about a variable named `event`, they could ask a different question and provide code that uses that and ask that, but as I read the question they did ask, that isn't what they asked.

Comment: I didn't make it into a generic question, I checked out the OP's fiddle link and based on that I could tell it was an issue with global events.  Anyway, I think we both agree what the OP is trying to do with global events isn't possible across browsers.  Other than passing the event through as a parameter which sounds like a painful solution if you have to update 100's of ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle.net/LU4yT/2  This jsfiddle link clearly has different results depending on the browsers you are using so, I would say the issue is browser specific...although I may have to agree with jfriend00 that while you can access the global event it's better (although more memory intensive) to pass the event through as a parameter.

Comment: In your jsFiddle, you picked a variable `event` that is defined globally in some browsers (non-standard behavior).  That is NOT what the OP's code example used.  I answered the question posted in the OP's actual code.  If they want to ask a different question about the global variable `event`, they could ask that, but that is not what they illustrated with their code.

Comment: I think it was miscommunication since the OP posted the jsFiddle.  I saw the post only once the jsFiddle example was added, and that is what the OP is asking as far as I can tell.